# Open a modern Microsoft Lists/Sharepoint list calendar in Outlook

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

Is there a way to open a modern Microsoft List Calendar in Outlook?

I have created a new calendar using Microsoft Lists.  I have created this using the standard Event content type.  Is there a way to get this calendar to open in Outlook.  If I was using the old Sharepoint style views I could use the "Connect to Outlook" button.

Answer (score -2):

There are some lists that can automatically sync with Outlook, which are Calendar List, Task List and Contact List. However, currently there is no method to connect normal list to outlook.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).